# Why do all Intel processors need a BIOS?

Tags: intel, bios

In the ARM world vendors supply their own BSPs to initialize board peripherals. Intel boards that you buy on the market all seems to come with some version of BIOS. Does BIOS do thing that BSPs cannot do? What if some hobbyist or engineer wants to do development using Intel processors but do not want anything to do with the BIOS? Why restrict programming with a layer of firmware that programmers have no source access to?

Comment: `Does BIOS do thing that BSPs cannot do?` Yes; a BSP is a *processor*, and (like other processors), is intended to run instructions. A BIOS is a *system* that's run *by* the BSP, and then handles initialization/basic testing of system components, and then loads the system OS (or bootloader, or whatever you want to do with the system).

Comment: right. BIOS is more like a BSP + bootloader. From BIOS you can call other bootloaders or chains of bootloaders.

Comment: is there no solutions out there that offers sources simple BSP and no bull-**** BIOS? I mean who wants to work with BIOS anyways. It's so outdated and developer-unfriendly.

Comment: `BIOS is more like a BSP + bootloader` Incorrect; in a multi-processor system, a BSP is simply just the (dynamically selected) single processor that is enabled for bootup, and the BSP *runs* the BIOS, and will then run whatever the BIOS loads (ie, bootloader, then OS).

Comment: I found "BSP is simply just the (...) single processor that is enabled for bootup" extremely confusing. You speak of BSP as if it's physical hardware. My view of a BSP is device drivers + startup routines for a specific board, hence the name "Board Support Package".

Comment: HA ok wow yeah we're definitely talking about different things. BSP (to me) means bootstrap processor. I don't have any experience with board support packages.

Comment: ...I would assume, though, that Intel isn't making it easy on programmers to do what you want to do simply because they (Intel) are one of the 'big guys' and can do whatever they want. They're not releasing processors for hobbyists, they're doing so on a large commercial scale. Allowing the openness that you're looking for could make it easier, for example, for someone to add Intel hardware to embedded systems, without any input from Intel. I would agree this is frustrating, but it's probably just the nature of Intel wanting full control over their intellectual property.

Comment: The point that I find more bull**** is that even a seemingly "Intel embedded processor powered hobbyist board" like Gelileo or Minnowboard have their own implementations of BIOS/UEFI. I mean what's the point here? The point of providing an "open-source" board is to have everything visible to the programmers. But these guys advertise themselves as "open-source" Intel board providers, but then embed their own BIOS/UEFIs. Then there's no difference in buying their "open-source" boards from buying normal mobo...

Comment: No, they don't need a BIOS. The only crucial part which is needed is FSP. The rest can be done in open software (Coreboot, U-Boot, etc). And JFYI: most of all modern SoCs contains a lot of firmwares inside (yes, including lovely ARM).

Answer (score 0):

Typically the BIOS is no layer of firmware but rather the firmware to boot the system. After booting control is provided by the OS such as Windows or Linux.

Comment: I understand this point. In ARM world vendors give you the SOURCES for BSP and possibly provide support for running an open-source bootloader i.e. u-boot. Why can't Intel or board manufacturers do the same. Say you want to use an Intel product for your next project, you'll need to write your own god-d**n BIOS from scratch since no vendors provide this to you...

Answer (score 0):

This is not really my area, but ....

The initials BSP are heavily overloaded. It appears you mean board support package and not Boot-strap-processor or one of the other computer related terms that use those initials.

It is my understanding that BSP's (board support packages) are primarily used for embedded systems and indeed, when I did a web search on 'Intel bsp', most of the hits were discussing Intel Galileo and Intel Edison boards, which are targeted toward IoT (internet of things) projects and other embedded projects. But I also found BSP's, for sale and for free, in executable and in source form, for a wide variety of Intel boards. If you are working with Linux, you might want to check out https://www.yoctoproject.org/ .
I don't know if there are any vendors packaging a BSP with an Intel board, but it is certainly possible.

Comment: Thanks froth. Yocto BSPs are another bull**** that I find floating around these days. If you care to look through them, you will NOT find a single source file. All they offer are recipes for customizing your Linux kernel and/or build process.

Comment: In another words it seems like Intel wants to get into the same boat (embedded processors market) as ARM processor vendors (like Freescale, TI, and such) by giving their bloated build system (Yocto) a way to customize source files for boards (BSP). Such a cheap marketing stint.

Comment: Well, the BIOS is closed source.  OTOH, if you want UEFI, check out the reference UEFI implementation from [TianoCore](http://www.tianocore.org/).  You will need the Intel board support package for your platform, though (to do chipset, microcode and processor setup).

Answer (score 0):

The only open source boot firmware for Intel processors that I know of is coreboot.  It doesn't support every board.  If you are building your own board, then you could customize it to work with your design.  A typical modern BIOS has lots of bloat such as ACPI and UEFI that you may or may not want.

Comment: U-Boot supports some Intel SoCs / platforms.